# Identifying multiple joysticks in Pyglet

Tags: pyglet, joystick

I'm making a game which may use one or two identical (i.e. same manufacturer and model name) joysticks with Pyglet. The game would save the key config in a file, but it's unable to distinguish, e.g. `START` button from left or right one.

I found a class named `pyglet.input.darwin_hid.PygletDevice` and its instance `device_identifier`, but the module seems to be prohibited from `import`ing...

Is there any way to identify the joysticks without using this, or to make this module `import`able?

Comment: You're supposed to use it through the http://pyglet-current.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyglet/pyglet.input.html module.

Comment: More specifically http://pyglet-current.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyglet/input/pyglet.input.Joystick.html#pyglet.input.Joystick in your case :)

Comment: @Torxed - I have tried it like `joystick.device.device_identifier`, but what I saw was like: https://pastebin.com/pY5TaxJn

Comment: If you've read the documentation, you'll notice that there's no `device_identifier` variable, technically. Either you do `joystick.device` that that's the device. Or you check the `joystick` value on each event, `Joystick.on_joyaxis_motion(joystick, axis, value)` which is the joystick identifier for that particular event.

Comment: `device_identifier` was shown from Visual Studio's autocomplete (maybe by IntelliSense.)

And the `joystick` value in each method was like `DirectInputDevice(name=FooBar Joystick 123 )` for **both** joysticks, then how should I write them separatedly in a file and load from it later?

Comment: `hash(joystick)` was no help because it returned different values for each run.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "**both**"? Sounds like they have a `.name` attribute. Obviously `hash(joystick)` would return something different each time. Assuming that it hashes the `__repr__` from `joystick` which probably includes a memory address which are different each run. I have no idea about your setup, what the data from both joysticks are. But please dig through `dir(joystick)` and see what functions or values you can benefit from.

Comment: Here are my code (https://pastebin.com/bpkbqswq) and console output (https://pastebin.com/9e3xzgM3). (I am using two joysticks of same model, so name can't be identifier.) I have tried `dir(joystick)`, but it seems that there is no identifier for each of them available from session to session...